# Evaluate the integral $\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-1}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I solved the question, but Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab both give me two completely different answers.

Here's my work:

Let $u = 2x$ and $a = 1$

Then $du = 2dx$ and $dx = \frac{du}{2}$

Then $\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-1}}$ = $\int\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}$

$\therefore \space\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-1}} = sec^{-1}(2x) + C$

Can anyone verify this solution?

Comment: You have $x^2$ in denominator!

Comment: That's it! I was way too confident going into that question :P

Comment: Is $\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-1}}$ = $\int\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}$ correct?

Comment: No, it should be $\int{\frac{1}{u^2\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}}$ according to Symbolab. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around that part though, since $u = 2x$, so when substituting $dx$ for $\frac{du}{2}$ it becomes $2\frac{x^2}{2}$, which simplifies to $x^2$ again, but that is not $u^2$, so I think I missed a step somewhere.

Comment: I get it now. It's easier to think about when you substitute $x=\frac{u}{2}$. Not sure what happened in the steps in my previous comment...

Comment: With $x=\dfrac{u}{2}$ you find $I=2\int\dfrac{du}{u^2\sqrt{u^2-1}}$.

Comment: I see that now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-1}}$

take $x=\dfrac{\sec \theta}{2}$, then $dx=\dfrac{\sec \theta\tan \theta}{2}d\theta$

Now $\sin\theta=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}{2x}$

When $x>\dfrac{1}{2}$, then $\sqrt{4x^2-1}=\tan \theta$

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-1}}=2\int \dfrac{\sec \theta\tan \theta}{\sec^2\theta\sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}}d\theta=2\int \dfrac{\sin\theta}{\tan \theta}d\theta\\=2\int \cos\theta d\theta=2\sin\theta+C=2\sin\Big(\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{2x}\Big)+C$$

Similarly, When $x<-\dfrac{1}{2}$, then $\sqrt{4x^2-1}=-\tan \theta$

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-1}}=-2\sin\Big(\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{2x}\Big)+C$$

Comment: Good Solution!.

Comment: This isn't the solution according to Symbolab or Wolfram Alpha

Comment: @Shea yes, you know that anti-derivative can have different answers.... for assurance try to draw the graph of these two different answers. You can understand easily.

Comment: @Shea: You shouldn't trust WA!

Comment: You can rewrite the antiderivative in a more typical form via the substitution $\sin \arccos u = \sqrt{1 - u^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $2x=\cosh u$ and then $I=\dfrac{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}{x}$.

Comment: For future reference, please leave short hints such as this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @2012ssohn Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $J= \int\frac{4}{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}dx$ and integrate by parts
\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-1}}dx
=& -\int\frac{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}{x^2}dx+ \int\frac{4}{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}dx\\
 =& \int \sqrt{4x^2-1}\ d\left(\frac1x\right)+ J
\overset{ibp}=\frac{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}{x}-J+J
\end{align}